# React app not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: node.js, reactjs, internet-explorer

My react app is not working on Internet explorer 11. It is working fine on edge and chrome.

I have already created a lot of files and i do not think I can try npx create-react-app.( As pointed out in the other answers for similar questions)

I have included this in both my index.js file but it does not work.

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image: This is the error that I am getting:]

I have looked at the links and they ask to resolve a bracket error but there is no issue when I see the code.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
      "name": "insurance_automation",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "config": "^3.1.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "multer": "^1.4.1",
        "mysql2": "^1.6.5",
        "node": "^11.15.0",
        "nodemailer": "^6.2.1",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
        "sequelize": "^5.8.6",
        "universal-cookie": "^4.0.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "server": "nodemon server",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm start\" "
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any special npm packages installed? I had this problem too and at some point of time I found out that it's caused by a faulty transpiled npm package.

Comment: I have included my package.json file, are there any questionable dependencies there?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8379 Please have a look at this

Comment: Try to refer this link may help you to understand the issue and you can get the information about possible solution. Ref: https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/facebook/create-react-app/6924/487331305

Comment: @sachinkalekar  I did see that post but it uses the same method as in the answer. I will try importing the files separately.

Comment: @AbdulAhad, did you check the link which I suggested you in my last comment? If not, You can check whether it can give any clue.

Comment: Hi abdhul ahad, did resolved this issue. I'm also facing the same issue kindly help me.

Answer (score 41):

This worked for me.

Update the development array in package.json

```
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

Add the below code in index.js in the src folder

```
// These must be the first lines in src/index.js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

Then delete the node_modules folder and run

```
npm install
```

IE does not support a lot of ES6+ features by default. For more info, refer [the create-react-app polyfill docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill#polyfilling-other-language-features).

Comment: Did not require `import 'react-app-polyfill/stable'`, the rest of the answer fixed it.

Comment: I had to add `import 'react-app-polyfill/stable'` only then it worked :) Thanks for this!

Comment: I also managed to get it to work using the `import 'react-app-polyfill/stable'` but I am unable to get it working on the published version of the app. Any ideas