# ReactJS works on IE localhost only

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer

I'm working on a ReactJS app and I'd like to make it run on IE.

Following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57870182/4489400, finally I can make it work on IE but only localhost (by npm start).

It works on the hosted PC when I go to http://localhost:3000 but I try to access it from other PC, change localhost to the name of the PC, it doesn't work on IE but still works on Chrome.

So what is the problem? Is the problem from IE on other PCs or I'm missing something? Both IEs are version 11.

Thank you.

[image]
It works on localhost

[image]
It doesn't work on IE on other PC

[image]
It works on Chrome on other PC

Comment: Try to use [F12 developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/bg182326(v=vs.85)) to check whether there has some error in IE browser. Besides, please try to compare the IE browser setting in the hosted PC and other PC (you could also try to [reset the IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings), and use the default setting).