# React App not working in Edge and IE. its working fine on Chrome and firefox. I tried using 'Polyfill' component but it did'nt work either

Tags: reactjs, npm, polyfills

I am creating a React application using visual studio code. The app is working fine on google chrome and Mozilla Firefox but it is not working on Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer v11. Actually i need the app to be working on Edge. Tried using 'Polyfill' component but it did'nt help. Help  me find a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React app not working in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421417/react-app-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: The question is already answered here, [Check this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421417/react-app-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: No its not working. i already tried that.

Comment: what error did you get in console

Comment: SCRIPT1002: SCRIPT1002: Syntax error

Comment: please go through the article https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6924